# Saving the content of an iFrame in MS Edge

Tags: javascript, iframe, microsoft-edge, save-as, execcommand

I have some JavaScript that worked well in Edge version 20.x.x but since upgrading to Edge version 25.x.x it has stopped working. It should save the content of an iFrame to a file which would contain some simple text. It might be worth pointing out that it still works in IE11, 10 etc.

```
txtArea1.contentDocument.execCommand("SaveAs", true, "xxxx.xls");
```

No error messages are thrown, it simply doesn't work.

Does anyone have any ideas why this has happened or possible workarounds?

---

Following on I found a solution using this:

```
var blobObject = new Blob([tableText]);
window.navigator.msSaveOrOpenBlob(blobObject, "download.xls.html");
```

I just identify IE11 or Edge and use the above and it works fine. Older versions can still use the previous code if the above fails.

Answer (score 0):

I would prefer to create a link with a `download` attribute pointing to `<iframe>`'s `src` with some query string which server detects and adds this header:

```
Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=xxxx.xls
```

Answer (score 0):

Following on I found a solution using this

var blobObject = new Blob([tableText]); 
window.navigator.msSaveOrOpenBlob(blobObject, "download.xls.html");

I just identify IE11 or Edge and use the above and it works fine. Older versions can still use the previous code if the above fails.